# Processing, Rotate rectangle using matrix?

Tags: matrix, rotation, processing

I am trying to rotate a rectangle without using the rotate function, but instead using a matrix..I know how to rotate a line using a matrix but all my attempts to rotate a rectangle have failed.

I dont think this is use full but heres is my code that rotates the line.

```
float[][] rotation;
float[] position;
float theta = 180;
float pointX;
float pointY;
void setup() {

  frameRate(60);
  size(600, 600);

  pointX = 0;
  pointY = 0;

 rotation = new float[2][2];
 position = new float[8];
}

 void draw() {
 background(200);
 theta = mouseX;

 position[0] = mouseY;
 position[1] = mouseY;

 position[2] = -mouseY;
 position[3] = mouseY;

 rotation[0][0] = cos(radians(theta));
 rotation[0][1] = -sin(radians(theta));
 rotation[1][0] = sin(radians(theta));
 rotation[1][1] = cos(radians(theta));

 float newpos[] = new float[8]; 

 newpos[0] += position[0] * rotation[0][0];
 newpos[1] += position[1] * rotation[0][1];  

 translate(width/2, height/2);

 line(0, 0, pointX+newpos[0], pointY+newpos[1]);
 line(0, 0, pointX+newpos[0] * -1, pointY+newpos[1] * -1);
```

}

Comment: Any reason you're not using android.graphics.Matrix?

Comment: its for school and the teacher did int mention anything about it....and he doesn't  want us to use short cuts....

Comment: Allright (though if this is a programming course and I were your teacher I'd blame you for crafting your own code instead of using an existing class). Where is your rectangle code?

Comment: umm its not there atm because i was not able to get it working..im not sure where to start

Comment: Could you perhaps rotate the four lines that represent the sides of the rectangle?

Comment: well ive attempted to do that but i cant get both lines rotating the same way EDIT got it working...i now basically have 2 lines rotating and it looks like a square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the lines behaves properly it is by chance... You have a crucial part of the calculation of the new x and y of the point not as it should have been. As you can find in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), you need to calculate the sin and cos in the matrix as you properly did, but when creating the new point you don't exactly do this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: mmmm where would i put this? where i thought it should be implemented now makes my line not rotate.

Comment: nvm i got it working thank you soooo much, i now got a wire frame of a square rotating. but of course my teacher wants to be red..but i believe that's for another topic

Answer (score 0):

Start by having a look at [pushMatrix()](http://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/popMatrix() and coordinate spaces.

Have a look at [Daniel Shiffman's tutorial](http://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) as well, it's pretty well explained.

If you need to get lower level than this, have a look at the [PMatrix2D](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PMatrix2D.html) class.
Notice there is a rotate() function. After you rotate, you can either simply apply
the matrix(using applyMatrix()) but you might as well be using push/pop matrix calls.
Another option is multiply vectors(rectangle corners) to the rotation matrix and draw the result/transformed points.

Comment: the issue is there is the rotate function...i got a square rotating like this before but my teacher said we cant have a rotate function basically he wants us to code what the rotate function does in the background.

Comment: [just in case](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PMatrix2D.java#L142), also probably your teacher held a lecture on transformation matrices ? (something [like this](http://people.bath.ac.uk/sej20/transform.html))

Comment: do you have clear homework requirements ? maybe your teacher expects you to whip out a basic 3x3 matrix class from scratch and implement the functions you will need(e.g. translate, rotate, scale). The concepts should be in your course material. You might also find [3D Math Primer](http://gamemath.com) useful and there's a chance the book might actually be in your university's library. 1st or 2nd doesn't matter that much in your case...the book is really nicely written and easy to understand

Comment: well...im in grade 12 not university :P and he i had a square rotating using push and pop matrix with a rotate function and he said it was wrong.