# Processing: Rotate rectangle

Tags: processing

I tried using this solution: [Processing, Rotate rectangle using matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498917/processing-rotate-rectangle-using-matrix) but they do not use the rotate() function, and I do.

I am trying to rotate an arm of a person I am drawing. The problem is that the location of all the body parts for each person (arms, head, body, etc) is set in a Person class, and since I cannot make that class static, I'm not sure how to access the 'angle' variable within the class to change the rotation. I am trying to make the angle of the arm based off of mouseY.

Person class:

```
public class Person {

  float height; 
  boolean isMale;
  float angle = 0;

  public Person(float height, boolean isMale, float angle) {
     this.height = height;
     this.isMale = isMale;
     this.angle = angle;
  }

  void display() {
       float x = random(-100, 1300);
       //float y = (height-1000)*200;
       float y = 0;
       //scale(height);
       fill(255);

       //legs
       rect(260+x, 320-y, 30, 130);
       rect(310+x, 320-y, 30, 130);

       //body
       if(isMale)
         rect(250+x, 170-y-height, 100, 170+height);
       else
         triangle(250+x-40, 320, 300+x, 150-height, 250+x+150, 320);

       //head
       ellipse(300+x, 150-y-height, 80, 80);

       //face
       fill(0);
       ellipse(285+x, 140-y-height, 10, 10);
       ellipse(315+x, 140-y-height, 10, 10);
       ellipse(300+x, 170-y-height, 30, 30);


       //arms
       fill(255);
       translate(275+x, 250-height); 
       rotate(radians(90));
       rect(0, 0, 150, 20);

     }

     public void updateAngle(float mouseYPos) {
        print(mouseYPos + "\n");
        angle += mouseYPos;
        //return angle+mouseYPos;
     }
}
```

Man class (which extends Person):

```
public class Man extends Person {

  float height;
  boolean isMale;
  //float angle;
   public Man(float height, boolean isMale, float angle) {
     super(height, isMale, angle);
     this.height = height;
     this.isMale = isMale;
     //this.angle = angle;
     } 

}
```

Main class with draw() function:

```
int x = width+1400;
float size = random(1, 1.7);
float speed = random(5, 15);
float angle = 0;

Person man1 = new Man(50, true, angle);

void setup() {
  size(1920, 1080);
  frameRate(80);
  background(100, 100, 255);
  //createRoad();


  man1.display();

  //Person man2 = new Man(0, true);
  //man2.display(); 

  //Person woman1 = new Woman(50, false);
  //woman1.display(); 
  //Person woman2 = new Woman(0, false);
  //woman2.display();
}

void draw() {
  Truck myTruck = new Truck(size, x);
  if (mousePressed) {
    myTruck.display();
    x-=speed; 
    man1.updateAngle(mouseY);
  }
}

void createRoad() {
  fill(100);
  rect(0, 450, 1920, 1080); 
  fill(255, 255, 0);
  rect(width-100, 750, 175, 25);
  rect(width-400, 750, 175, 25);
  rect(width-700, 750, 175, 25);
  rect(width-1000, 750, 175, 25);
  rect(width-1300, 750, 175, 25);
  rect(width-1600, 750, 175, 25);
  rect(width-1900, 750, 175, 25);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to access the `angle` function?

Answer (score 0):

First move `man1.display();` to `draw()` then inside `display()` you must use the `angle` variable somewhere, for example:

```
//arms
fill(255);
translate(275+x, 250-height); 
rotate(radians(angle));
rect(0, 0, 150, 20);
```